# Rails API Does not split Json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Weird problem. If the class at the bottom was a module, split the Json without problems, if it was only methods, also works, but the problem is.. when it is a class, it does not split the Json anymore, and returns an empty array.. however, if being a class, I do a puts the object, it actually puts it..
Any thoughts about why? How can I fix it?

I have this controller:

```
 def index
   begin
     call_employee_work_locations_api
      rescue => ex
      render :json => {"service unavailable": "0001" }, :status => :service_unavailable
   end 
 end
```

I have this service:

```
def call_employee_work_locations_api
   auth = {:username=>ENV["USERNAME"], :password=>ENV["PASSWORD"]}
   employee_locations = HTTParty.get(employee_work_Location_url , :basic_auth => auth)
   #serialize_work_location(employee_locations) 
   serializer = EmployeeSerializer.new
   serializer.serialize_work_location(employee_locations)
end
```

I have this builder:

```
json.array!(@top_locations) do |location|
   json.extract! location, :name, :description, :latitude, :longitude
end
```

I have this class:

```
class EmployeeSerializer

    def serialize_work_location(employee_locations)
        employee_locations= JSON.parse(employee_locations)
        locations=[]

        employee_locations["work_locations"].each do |attributes|
           location = Location.new(attributes["latitude"],attributes["longitude"],attributes["description"],attributes["name"])
          locations.push(location)
        end
        employee_locations_selector(locations)
    end 

    def top_office_location_selector(locations, city)
        top_locations=[]
        locations.each do |office|
            if office.name == city[0] then top_locations.push(office) end
            if office.name == city[1] then top_locations.push(office) end
        end
        @top_locations = top_locations
        p @top_locations <--- it prints the object perfectly, but does not pass to the view, I get an empty array instead.
     end

     def employee_locations_selector(locations)
        city = locations.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |locations, counts| counts[locations.name] += 1 }.max_by{|k,v| v}
        top_office_location_selector(locations, city)
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The instance variable `@top_locations` is being set within the scope of the `EmployeeSerializer` class, not your controller. As such it's just a normal instance variable and so Rails knows nothing about it. You can assign the return value of `#top_office_location_selector` to an instance variable in the controller and it should work.

On a side note, the code would be cleaned up a lot by using `#map` over `#each`.

Comment: I can not believe I did not see that.. honestly :| thanks a lot